# Get PR Number OR Branch Name in GitHub Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to deploy a serverless application on merge into develop & master AND on PR request. I want the stage name to correspond to the branch name OR pull request number.

This is the step in question, but github.event.push.ref is the entire branch ref (i.e. ref/head/master) etc. And I just want "master" or "develop". Is there anyway to use this same syntax as below to get pull_request number OR branch name?

```
      # Deploy API Tests
      - name: Deploy API
        run: yarn deploy --stage ${{ github.event.pull_request.number || github.event.push.ref }}
        working-directory: api
```

Answer (score 0):

If the shell you're using is `bash` or another POSIX shell, it's easy enough to do this:

```
run: 'yarn deploy --stage $(echo "${{ github.event.pull_request.number || github.event.push.ref }}" | sed -e 's!^refs/heads/!!')'
```

That will strip off the `refs/heads/` prefix and leave you with just the branch name.  If you were not using a PR, then you could also use this, which would have Git abbreviate the name to just the branch or tag name:

```
run: 'yarn deploy --stage $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref "${{ github.event.push.ref }}")'
```